# How could I find out the breed of my dog?

Tags: dogs, breeding

My dog was very smart, he was around 80 pounds, totally has no interest and offensive to other people, only loves the family members,  he seldom barks except he found something wrong, he is protective if someone shows dangerous behaviors. He did not like other puppies, even bite them sometimes if other puppies try hard to play with him, we have to keep him away from other dogs, except that, his personality is perfect for us.

He was from Kazakstan and lived with us for 6 years, we missed him very much, and we like his personality very much. We have lost him for almost 10 years, and we still brought him up occasionally.

What's another sorry is that we did not know what's the breed of him, how can I find out what's the breed of my dog?

**When he was 6 months old.**
[image: 6 months old][1]]

**When he was 6 months old.**
[image]

**When he was 2 years old.**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I sadly assume your question is out of focus. Because we could only suggest and nobody could give you a real answer. Additionally find a breed out of pictures is very inaccurate. You could ask about "How could I find out the breed of my dog" instead.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Understood, thank you.

Comment: It's effectively impossible to really tell based off just looks alone; the only way to know for sure is to get a genetic test done. I've personally known a dog who looks almost exactly like a labrador, was assumed for years to be a lab-pit mix, and then when tested turned out to have no lab at all.

Answer (score 3):

He looks a bit like a Labrador Boxer mix. However, the Boxador usually has a more black mouth area, even though these are often mixed with the Black Mouth Cur. Boxadors are medium to large in size, highly intelligent, and very loyal to their families.

Comment: Somebody told me that he is a Lab Pitbull mix, but when I go through the pictures, neither Boxador nor Lab Pitbull looks like him. Thank you.

Comment: He looks like a Rhodesian Ridgeback, but he did not has the ridgeback.